# Contraction to a discrete metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

$f:X\rightarrow Y$  is a  contraction  where  $Y$  is  a  discrete  metric  space

The  question is :: "*What*  *can*  *you*  *say*  *about*  *f*  $?$"

$$d(f(x),f(x'))\lt d(x,x')$$  Now  there  are  two  possibilities  for $d(f(x),f(x'))$ ;  $1$  or  $0$.

I  don't  know  what  to  do  next  or cannot  think  of  what  to  say  about  $f$ .

Please  help.

Answer (score 3):

For each $x\in X$ let $B_x=\{x'\in X:d(x,x')\le 1\}$.

- Show that $f(x')=f(x)$ for all $x'\in B_x$.
- Show that if $B_{x_1}\cap B_{x_2}\ne\varnothing$, then $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$.

Now suppose that $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a sequence in $X$ converging to $x$.

- What can you say about $f(x_n)$ if $d(x_n,x)<1$? What does this tell you about the sequence $\langle f(x_n):n\in\Bbb N\rangle$?
- What can you now say about $f$?

If you want to get a little more of a feel for the situation, you might think about the following examples, though they have no direct bearing on the question.

- Show that if $X$ is $\Bbb R$ with the usual metric, then $f$ must be a constant function.
- Show that if $X$ is $\Bbb R$ with the metric $$d(x,y)=\begin{cases}0,&\text{if }x=y\\2,&\text{otherwise}\;,\end{cases}$$ then $f$ can be any function from $X$ to $Y$.